# turning dataframe into dictionary and keeping all values

Tags: python-3.x, string, pandas, list, dictionary

```
import pandas as pd
text = [list(['(1-100-133-1710)']), 'nan', 'nan']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Text': text ,
                   'IDs': ['A11','A11','C11'],
                          }) 
df
    IDs Text
0   A11 [(1-100-133-1710)]
1   A11 nan
2   C11 nan
```

I have the following `df`

My goal is to make `df` into a dictionary

So I try the following

```
to_d = dict(zip(df.IDs,df.Text))
```

I get the following output

```
 {'A11': 'nan', 'C11': 'nan'}
```

But this output is missing key `A11` and value `[(1-100-133-1710)]` from row `0` in `df`. Ideally, I would like the following output but duplicated keys aren't allowed in python dictionaries

```
{'A11': '[(1-100-133-1710)]', 'A11': 'nan', 'C11': 'nan'}
```

So instead, I  want the following output, which combines both values from `A11` into one common value list which keeps the same key `A11`

```
{'A11': '[[(1-100-133-1710)]', 'nan'], 'C11': 'nan'}
```

How do I get my desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we can using `to_dict`

```
df.groupby('IDs').Text.apply(list).to_dict()
Out[431]: {'A11': [['(1-100-133-1710)'], 'nan'], 'C11': ['nan']}
```